# Align fabric edges with curve

Tags: modeling

I made a bumpy fabric and I need to align its edges with the parent object so there are no holes between them:
[image]
[image]

I can do this if the object is simple just by using the proportional edit and scaling it to zero on the Z axis, but I have trouble with more complex shapes. Maybe there's a modificator that allows me to align the edge with the curve or something like that?
[image]